# Display the argument under the line of user after running php in mac terminal

Tags: php, command-line-arguments

I’m writing a very simply php script that take a path to a command line argument and prints it out.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $argument1 = $argv[1];
    $argument2 = $argv[2];
    echo $argv[1]; 

    ?>
```

Output:

```
user-mbp:desktop$ php test_script.php /desktop/my/path/ 
/desktop/my/path/user-mbp:desktop user$ 

You can see the result "/desktop/my/path/" is behind the line of user-mbp:desktop $
```

But I want the result is like:

```
    /desktop/my/path/              <- Line 1
    user-mbp:desktop user$         <- Line 2
```

Do you have any hint for my code?  I’m appreciated it.

I tried the command `echo $argv[1] ."\n"`, but the result is weird:

```
/desktop/my/path/

    user-mbp:desktop user$
```

You can see is does show under the line of user. 
But I don't quite understand why the line `user-mbp:desktop user$` shifts and goes to the next line! Thanks again!

Comment: you forgot the newline. `echo $argv[1], "\n"`. php doesn't do linebreaks for you automatically, so the output ends exactly where the data to be output does. that means the command prompt shows up exactly at the end of the output, and not on a new line.

Comment: if you are doing this multiple times, create afunction: `function writeln($str){echo $str ."\n";} writeln($argv[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

For command line scripts, you're going to always need to add a newline at the end of your echo'd content. So, this:

```
echo $argv[1] . "\n";
```

Your shell won't do that for you automatically, and PHP won't do it automatically because it *shouldn't* do it automatically, and you didn't explicitly tell it to.